# Strange javascript looping behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, where need to iterate to find and return the corresponding value.

```js
function getCost(val) {
  let arr = JSON.parse('[ { "hours": 1, "cost": 100 }, { "hours": 2, "cost": 50 }, { "hours": 3, "cost": 20 }, { "hours": 4, "cost": 10 }, { "hours": 5, "cost": 5 } ]')
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i]
    let hours = parseInt(item['hours'], 10)

    if (hours == val) {
      return item['cost']
    }
    /*this condition not working*/
    if (hours > val) {
      alert('exceed') //this not called at all
      return arr[arr.length - 1]['cost']
    }

  }
}

alert(getCost(4)) /*this works*/

alert(getCost(8)) /*this not work, give undefined*/
```

But why when the val condition more then the compare value, it not working. The `hours > val` simply doesn't work. 
Any mistake I made?

Comment: You do not have any items with an `hours` greater than 8 (largest number of hours is 5)

Comment: If you go through you function step-by-step - which return should be triggered for `getCost(8)` ? Currently none of the conditions matches, so the functions runs through and returns the (implicit) `undefined`.

Comment: There is nothing strange about this behavior. Since your val in this case (8) doesn't equal any of the dictionary's hours attribute in the list, and nor does it meet the if condition (none of those hours values are greater than 8 the val), your function doesn't return anything, so its effectively `undefined` value.

Comment: You are are rights, clearly I misunderstanding the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is expected because there is no condition to satisfy your "not working" `if` block. You could check on the last index like this instead

```js
function getCost(val){
let arr = JSON.parse('[ { "hours": 1, "cost": 100 }, { "hours": 2, "cost": 50 }, { "hours": 3, "cost": 20 }, { "hours": 4, "cost": 10 }, { "hours": 5, "cost": 5 } ]')
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var item = arr[i]
        let hours = parseInt(item['hours'],10)

        if(hours == val){
            return item['cost']
        }
  /*check if it is already the last iteration of the loop*/
      if(i==arr.length-1){
           alert('exceed') 
            return arr[arr.length - 1]['cost']          
        }

    }
}

alert(getCost(4))

alert(getCost(8))
```

Comment: You are are rights, clearly I misunderstanding the concept. Thanks for the prompt answer